# melt and append data using reshape2 functions in R

Tags: r, reshape

This should be simple but for some reason I'm stuck.  I have data that looks like

```
A <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(1))
B <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(1))
C <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(1))

method1 <- list(A=A,B=B,C=C)
method2 <- list(A=A,B=B,C=C)

biglist <- list(method1, method2)
```

And I'd like to reformat the data to look like

```
x y z   dataset  method
- - -   ---       -----
1 1 1    A          1
1 0 2    A          1
1 0 3    A          1
1 1 3    A          1
1 1 1    B          1
1 0 2    B          1
1 0 3    B          1
1 1 3    B          1
1 1 1    C          1
1 0 2    C          1
1 0 3    C          1
1 1 3    C          1
1 1 1    A          2
1 0 2    A          2
1 0 3    A          2
1 1 3    A          2
1 1 1    B          2
1 0 2    B          2
...
```

melt doesn't quite do what I want because it collapses my x/y/z variable headings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data.frames should have a primary key, 
e.g., an identifier column, or a column with unique values -- 
otherwise, you will end up with the x, y, z 
coordinates of a point in several unrelated rows.
I will assume that `x` is such a column.

You may also have to call `dcast` after `melt`,
if the resulting data.frame is too vertical.

```
library(reshape2)
d <- melt(biglist, id.vars="x")
d <- dcast( d, L1 + L2 + x ~ variable )
```

Comment: Brilliant, I think I just forgot/never understood id.vars:  How about a little cleaner solution: d <- melt(biglist, id.vars=c("x", "y", "z"))